# Warning: open dir: not implemented

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, and I'm trying to build a script. When I load the script, I get the following error:

Warning: opendir(http://www.hetweerinboskamp.nl/voorpagina/movies) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: not implemented

```
<?php
    $hal ='';
    $dir ='http://www.hetweerinboskamp.nl/voorpagina/movies';
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        // Loop the folders
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if(strlen($file) > 4) {
                $rawd = parsename($file);
                $hal.= 'new Date('.substr($rawd,0,4).', '.substr($rawd,4,2).'-1, '.substr($rawd,6,2).'),';
                 //$hal.= $rawd.',';
             }

            closedir($handle);
         }
```

Comment: This php script is running on the server from the webpage

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`opendir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) is used to open a local directory and since PHP 5.0.0 on an ftp directory.

If your PHP code runs on www.hetweerinboskamp.nl then `/voorpagina/movies` is actually a local directory and you can do this:

```
$dir ='<wwwroot>/voorpagina/movies';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
```

where `wwwroot` is the root of the filesystem as seen by your php code.

If you're trying to download content from another website, try e.g. [`file_get_contents()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Note that if the remote server lists the content of a directory the listing is in fact an HTML page generated on the fly by the server. You may find yourself needing to parse that page. A better approach is to check whether the server offers some sort of API where it sends back the content in a standardized form, e.g. in JSON format.

Answer (score 6):

`opendir` operates on directories on a filesystem, not HTTP URIs.

While some HTTP URIs return directory listings (the one you are using doesn't, it is a 404 error), those listings as HTML documents generated by the webserver and are not actual directories.

Answer (score 1):

Manual claims this function works with URL's, however, it appears it doesn't.

Use a local path (either relative or absolute). For example, `'./voorpagina/movies'`. This has solved a similar problem to me before. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most remote servers does not send a directory listing back as such opendir cannot understand what your trying to do so it cant work.

You will need to use something like ftp, here is an example: http://php.net/manual/en/ftp.examples-basic.php or cURL