# PHP readdir() and opendir() working locally but not working on live server

Tags: php, directory, localhost, readdir, opendir

I was getting below error so changed

```
opendir(http://test.myserv.com/Optfolder/upload/upload) 

[function.opendir]: failed to open dir: not implemented
```

so changed  to  **file_get_contents($dir)**

But then in next I got this error

```
readdir(): supplied argument is not a valid Directory resource
```

What should I do?

I use below code to read folder images is there any option for opendir and readdir so ic an use them for my purpose?

In $dir I get full path like **http://testserv.com/optfolder/upload**

```
$dir = opendir($dir);

    while ($file = readdir($dir)) { 
       if (preg_match("/.png/",$file) || preg_match("/.jpg/",$file) || preg_match("/.gif/",$file) ) { 
       $string[] = $file;
       }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: open dir: not implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018003/warning-open-dir-not-implemented)

Answer (score 2):

`opendir()` cannot be used on a URL as it opens a directory relative to the filesystem. This is also a potential duplicate of [Warning: open dir: not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018003/warning-open-dir-not-implemented).

`readdir()` is also exactly the same as `opendir()` in regards to how it locates directories.

Please take a look at the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php to fully understand it.

Comment: I don't follow, to open the upload folder you will need to use your web root so `opendir("{$webroot}/Optfolder/upload/upload");` or something similar.

Comment: hi i got path like opendir("http://testserv.server.com/Optfolder/upload/upload"), but stil get the same error..What should i use in place of $webroot?

Comment: You're still using an HTTP directive. You have to use directory paths only.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean webroot, I mean the the full filesystem path to the folder, or the relative filesystem path. So if that PHP file is in your base directory then you should be able to use `"Optfolder/upload/upload"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `opendir()` on HTTP urls. You need to specify a relative directory path instead. See [opendir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
file_get_contents('http://testserv.com/optfolder/upload');
```