# Working solution to get file names inside server folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've used multiple solutions here on Stackoverflow but I can't make any of them work properly (Nodejs is not accepted).

I have a path filled with mp3 files and I want to return the file names.

The lasted thing I tried was this:

in the `getFiles` folder of my server, I have a PHP file named `files.php` and a JS file named `scripts.js` and `index.html`

PHP code:

```
<?php
     $dir = 'mysite/folderOf/audio/';
    // Store the scandir results in a variable
    $files = scandir($dir);
    // Encode the array in JSON and echo it
    echo json_encode($files);
?>
```

Javascript:

```
$.get( "files.php", function( data ) {
          console.log(data);
});
```

The directory where the mp3 files exist is: `mysite/folderOf/audio/`

The result of the code above is:

[image]

I need to return an array with filenames of `mysite/folderOf/audio/` directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018003/warning-open-dir-not-implemented). Regardless of being able to fix this, it's worth noting that access the file system on a webserver is a very bad idea, both for performance and security reasons.

Comment: How will you access a directory via http?

Comment: This is the directory I used: `https://files.000webhost.com/https://round-arm-authority.000webhostapp.com/audio%20experiment/audios/`

Comment: @m.rp I very much doubt on a shared host `mysite` will be in the root folder

Comment: you need to make sure this directory `mysite/folderOf/audio/` is inside the folder that has `file.php`

Comment: Step 1: Learn what the difference between an HTTP URL, and a file system path is. scandir only works with the latter.

Answer (score 2):

**try this if it works**

```
    <?php
        // open this directory 
        $Directory = opendir('mysite/folderOf/audio');
        // get each entry
        while($entryName = readdir($Directory)) {
            $fileArray[] = $entryName;
        }
        // close directory
        closedir($Directory);
        //  count elements in array
        sort($fileArray);
        $indexCount = count($fileArray);
        // loop through the array of files and print them all in a list
        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
            $extension = substr($fileArray[$index], -3);
            if ($extension == 'mp3'){
                echo '<a class="iconMP3" href="mysite/folderOf/audio/' . $fileArray[$index] . '"/>' . $fileArray[$index] . '</a>';
            }   
        }
   ?>
```